# Laravel Vue SPA login

Tags: laravel, vue.js, authentication

I just created Vue + Laravel SPA login but I'm not sure if it's safe enough. I'm new in VUE :)

I'm using JWT Auth. When user enter credentials and submit form, Auth on Laravel side returns user model with token. This user is stored in local storage. In my Vue router I created middleware which run beforeEach view change. This is working good but there is not actual token in database related to this user. When I manually change token in storage I'm still passing middleware because token is not checked anymore. It just check if exists in local storage... Should I store token in DB and check it on every view change? Or...??

Comment: Are you using a JWT library/framework server side? If so, which one?? If not, you can try something like https://github.com/codecasts/laravel-jwt - my point is - these libraries should have a way for you to not only check for JWT existence, but to also verify the JWT integrity.  The entire point of JWT is to store 'session state' on the client (so you don't have to keep track of that server side - aka save anything server side). You sign the JWT and verify its signature (not just it's existence) server side. Sounds like you're just checking for it's existence which is no bueno!

Comment: @MattOestreich I was following this link: https://medium.com/@gitesky14/how-to-authenticate-using-jwt-auth-in-laravel-5-6-vue-spa-ac85963db0ed

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Laravel, but it doesn't sound like you're verifying the token when it is sent.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like its safe, no :)

I've never used Laravel, so I can't talk about it specifically, but I can explain how the process is suppose to work.

In your server, you should have a middlewere or somekind of logic that reads the token and verifies it integrity. The token itself is just a Base64 string with three components

1. Header
2. Payload (the actual data)
3. Signature

If you have the token, its easy to read the payload, because its just Base64 string. So its not enough just to read that, you need to make sure that the signature is correct.

When you create a JWT token you do so with a secret, when there's a request to your server. The server should verify the signature to make sure that this is a valid token. If you don't have the secret you can't verify the signature. Only you should have the secret.

This stops "me as an attacker" to send a token with some fake payload. By verifying the signature you are making sure that this is the token you created, not some fake token I'm sending to your website.

You should also not store that token in a local storage. Local storage should never contain information like token or password, because is just a dictionary/map that's accessable for everybody. So I can make a website that reads the local storage, get the token you created, and since this is your token with a correect signature I can now make requests to your website.

I would reccomend storing a JWT token in a httpOnly cookie on https (safe: true option in most environments). The browser can't read httpOnly cookies, only the server.

When making requests from the VueJS app to the server, like saving a blog post the server should

1. Never trust the payload in the JWT blindly.
2. Never trust user information from the VueJS app.
3. Always verify the user on the server side (by verifying the signature of the token in your example)

For example

```
methods: {
  saveBlogPost() {
    axios.post('/api/save', {
      title: 'My blog title'
      userId: 'bergur'
    })
  }
}
```

Your server should never, never read that userId sent from the VueJS app. The JWT middlewere should check the JWT, verify its integrity and then use the information from the payload.

Edit: I answered a similar post about securing VueJS apps. You can find it here: [VueJS Secure with Auth0 - How is it secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56295914/vuejs-secure-with-auth0-how-is-it-secure/56296182#56296182)

Basically: Its fine to store information in the client that help to make the user interface make sense, but when doing the actual work like saving into the database or fetching some private data the server should always verify the user.

Answer (score 0):

it's important to protect your server side routes. The solution i used for this was using the php jwt library `lcobucci/jwt` in `Laravel`.

I'll explain using the default and more simple approach JWT secret strategy and not a private/public key strategy(like RSA).

No matter what framework you are using the steps for a `JWT` authentication will always be the same:

1. User logs in.
2. User credentials(email/username and password) sent as a post request
   from your client side(vue) to your server side(Laravel)
3. In the server side verify the credentials are correct
4. If correct, with a jwt secret, sign a JWT token for this user.
5. send the created jwt token as a response to the client.
6. Store the JWT token in your localStorage and add it to the header
   for future requests.

A simple Server side implementation will include

1. Creating a `jwt secret` env variable
2. Creating a sign-in route
3. Creating a middleware for incoming requests to verify token

For these steps, create a `JWT_SECRET` env variable. This will be a big random string. You can use any [random string generator for this](https://www.random.org/strings/). example:

```
JWT_SECRET=bX7fsuHzOksB27Pwh31qmazMsalw4bchu7Ft1X4PMOhO23Zq8nwBKA0FZQOK
```

Create an api `sign-in` route 
`Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@signIn');`

`app/Http/Controllers/AuthenticateController.php`

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Services\JWTService;

class AuthenticateController extends Controller
{

    protected $jwt;

    public function __construct(JWTService $jwt)
    {
        $this->jwt = $jwt;
    }

    public function signIn(Request $request){
        $token = $this->jwt->createToken();
        $response = response()->json([  
            'message' => StatusCode::$texts[StatusCode::HTTP_OK],
            'data' => [ 'token' => (string)$token]
        ], StatusCode::HTTP_OK);

        return $response;

    }
}
```

`app/Services/JWTService.php`

```
<?php 
namespace App\Services;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Builder;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac\Sha256;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Parser;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Token;

class JWTService
{
    public function createToken($privilege = 'externalUser'){
        // eval(\Psy\sh());

        $signer = new Sha256();
        $key = new Key(env('JWT_SECRET')); // vindo null
        $time = time();
        $token = (new Builder())->issuedBy($privilege)->expiresAt($time + 3600)->getToken($signer, $key);
        //->withClaim('uid', 1) // Configures a new claim, called "uid"

        return $token;
    }

    public function parseString($bearerToken) : Token {
        return (new Parser())->parse($bearerToken);
    }

    public function verify($token){
        $signer = new Sha256();
        $key = new Key(env('JWT_SECRET'));
        if(!$token->verify($signer, $key))
            abort(401, 'Unauthorized access.');

        return true;
    }

}
```

To protect your routes, add a middleware for all incoming requests (except sign-in). The authorization logic using jwt claims will be your to make.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Parser;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Key;
use Lcobucci\JWT\Signer\Hmac\Sha256;
use OutOfBoundsException;
use BadMethodCallException;

use Closure;

class Authorization
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        try {

            $bearerToken = $request->bearerToken();

            if(!isset($bearerToken))
                abort(401, 'Unauthorized access.');

            $token = (new Parser())->parse($bearerToken); // Parses from a string
            $signer = new Sha256();
            $key = new Key(env('JWT_SECRET'));
            if(!$token->verify($signer, $key))
                abort(401, 'Unauthorized access.');
            return $next($request);

        } catch(OutOfBoundsException $e){
            abort(401, 'Requested data is not configured.');
        } catch(BadMethodCallException $e){
            abort(403, 'Token not signed.');
        }

    }
    // $token->getHeaders(); // Retrieves the token header
    // $token->getClaims(); // Retrieves the token claims
    // $token->getClaim('iss');
    // $token->getClaim('exp');
}
```

Add your middleware to `kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'tokenAuth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authorization::class
];
```

This way you can add your middleware to `routes/api.php` this way:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'tokenAuth'], function(){
        Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
        Route::resource('Foo', 'FooController');
 }
```

I strongly recommend to read [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x) and [lcobucci/jwt](https://github.com/lcobucci/jwt) to better understand the steps and how to achieve a safe and good solution using `jwt claims` and `Laravel` built in tools.