# what to do after authenticating the log-in credentials in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, post

I was building my chat app and i prepared the login page to authenticate the user logging into the application not the question if what should i do with it, I used POST method to get the credentials and compared it with the database,  now how should i send this to the front end page so as to make user logg in and send message by the username they have logged in.

i do not want a piece of code but rather I'd like to have a suggestion on what should i do next and what should i do next, if i just send the plain username into the frontend then i am afraid that users can change its value and pretend that they are someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You don't send it to the frontend page. You never send password or any other sensitive information to the clientside/frontend/browser

The flow is roughly like this.

1. Frontend has a login form that posts to the server
2. Server gets the username and password
3. Server authenticates and creates a session
4. Frontend gets information that this user is now logged in.
5. Every action this user takes has to be check on the server side.

You can also check my answer on similar thougt:
[VueJS Secure with Auth0 - How is it secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56295914/vuejs-secure-with-auth0-how-is-it-secure/)

Where the author asks:

> If I set some variable like isLoggedIn = true or isAdminUser = true,
> what stops the user from manipulating the DOM and forcing these values
> to true?

The short answer is nothing. You don't do any authentication on the client side.  Its ok to have some variables like isLoggedIn or isAdminUser to make the interface make sense but the server code should always to the actual authentication or authorization.